# How do I load a C dll into a C# code?

Tags: c#, c

I am in the need of using some functions in a C made program. To test I defined the following :

This is my .h file :

```
namespace amt
{
    class AMT_EXPORT FaceRecognition
    {   
        public:
            std::string amt_test_string(std::string in);
    };  
};
```

This is my .cpp file :

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "api_shared.h"
#include <sys/stat.h>

using namespace std;

std::string amt::FaceRecognition::amt_test_string (std::string in)
{
    std::string s="in: "+in;
    std::cout<<s<<std::endl;

    return s;
}
```

I am trying to invoke the method like this :

```
 const string str = "C:\\minimal.dll";
[DllImport(str)]
public static extern string amt_test_string(string input);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myinput = "12";
    string myoutput = "";
    myoutput = amt_test_string(myinput);
    Console.WriteLine(myoutput);
    Console.Read();

}
```

But im getting an error saying that it cannot find the entry point named amt_test_string..why so? I am a newbie in C btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a C DLL, that's a C++ DLL.  C and C++ are *not* the same language.  In particular, C++ has name mangling, so the function name which gets exported to the DLL is *decorated*.

I'd strongly recommend that you avoid having C++ exports in your DLL for that reason.  If you use only C exports, the symbol name will be predictable (i.e. will not depend on the specific details of how your C++ compiler decorates names), and you won't have to worry about runtime differences, like how your C++ standard library implements `std::string`.

I'd recommend your DLL export look like this:

```
extern "C"  // This says that any functions within the block have C linkage
{

// Input is 'in', output gets stored in the 'out' buffer, which must be 'outSize'
// bytes long
void DLLEXPORT amt_FaceRecogniztion_amt_test_string(const char *in, char *out, size_t outSize)
{
    ...
}

}
```

This interface does not rely on any particular library's `std::string` implementation, and C# knows how to martial `char*` parameters as C strings.  However, memory management is more complicated, as you need to figure out an upper bound on how big the output is going to be and pass in an appropriately sized bufer.